# Encoding issue on SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, encoding, character-encoding, latin1

I'm working with SQL Server database; database instance encoding is "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS".

The following code:

```
UPDATE ...
SET field = CHAR(136)
WHERE...
```

puts in field the following symbol: ˆ

But! In Latin1 code table 127-159 codes are just not defined! How comes it inserts this symbol?

And what's more confusing, when I read this field value to string variable in C# and convert it to char, I get the code 710 instead of 136.

I tried to use encoding conversion:

```
var latin1Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
var test = latin1Encoding.GetBytes(field); // field is a string read from db
```

But in this case I get code 94 which is ^ (looks similar, but it's not the same, and I need exactly same).

Comment: If you want things to be exactly the same, I think you should use the binary collation. Conversion across different encoding is always lossy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But! In Latin1 code table 127-159 codes are just not defined!

In ISO-8859-1, character 136 is defined, but it's a seldom-used and largely pointless control character.

But SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, despite the name “Latin1”, is not ISO-8859-1. It's the Western European ANSI code page, 1252, which is similar to ISO-8859-1, but has a bunch of different symbols in the range 128–159.

Character 136 in code page 1252 is U+02C6 MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT, `ˆ`; decimal code point number 710.

> in this case I get code 94 which is ^

Yes, you're asking for a conversion to ISO-8859-1, which doesn't include the character U+02C6, so you get the “best fit fallback”, which is a character that looks a bit like that one you wanted. This is usually a bad thing; many of the fallbacks chosen are highly questionable. You can change this behaviour using an [EncoderFallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoderfallback.aspx), for example to throw an exception instead.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there's several conversion taking place here.

1. When you use `Char(136)` the number is an **ASCII** code, but since the number 136 is outside the standard ASCII set the character you get is the one defined by [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). That character is the circumflex.
2. In addition to defining the encoding of non-unicode columns, the collation also establishes some rules for translating between non-unicode characters and unicode ones when attempting to store the non-unicode character in a unicode field. If no conversion is defined you'll tend to get a ?, but in this case you get the character with the unicode code-point U+02C6. The important thing to appreciate is that the collation establishes an equivalence between the characters because it was decided that they are similar/equivalent. It has nothing to do with the actual values.
3. Finally, you used the iso-8859-1 encoding to get the numeric code of the circumflex in that encoding which is 94.